# $a\otimes(-a) = a \otimes (1-a) + a^{-1}\otimes(1-a^{-1})$???

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

J. Browkin writes in his article "K-Theory, Cyclotomic Equations, and Clausen's Function" (which appears on Chapter 11 of Lewin's book "Structural properties of polylogarithms") that for any field $F$ and $a\in F^\times$, $a\neq 1$,

$$a\otimes(-a) = a \otimes (1-a) + a^{-1}\otimes(1-a^{-1}).$$

I have two questions:

1. Is this tensor over $\mathbb Z$?
2. How is this equality true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 'guess' - I'm afraid that I don't know anything about $K$-theory, for instance - but I did get the expected equality.

View $F^\times$ as a (multiplicative) abelian group, and hence a $\mathbb Z$ module: e.g., $n\cdot(a)= (a^n)$, etc... The tensor product is indeed over $\mathbb Z$, but above, in your question (and in what follows), the group operation on $F^\times\otimes F^\times$ is written using addition, while the group structure on $F^\times$ is written using multiplication. So, for instance,
$$ a\otimes 1 = 0, $$ 
and $$(a\otimes b) - (a \otimes c) = a\otimes (b/c),\tag{*}$$ 
and
$$ a\otimes b^{-1}= a^{-1}\otimes b= - (a\otimes b)\tag{**}$$
all hold true.

Therefore, as a special case of $(*)$:
$$ a\otimes (-a) - a\otimes (1-a) = a \otimes (-a /( 1-a)). $$
But, of course, $$-a/ (1-a)= 1/ (1-a^{-1}) = (1-a^{-1})^{-1}.$$
Therefore, from $(**)$, one gets 
$$ a \otimes (-a / (1-a))= a\otimes (1-a^{-1})^{-1} = a^{-1}\otimes (1-a^{-1}),$$ 
from which follows the desired equality.

Comment: I can make sense of everything you're writing except $a\otimes 1=0$. Could you explain where that's coming from? I do get $a\otimes b + a\otimes 1 = a \otimes b$ but don't know why $c\otimes b + a\otimes 1 = c\otimes b$.

Comment: @Bananach If $M$ and $N$ are abelian groups (written additively), certainly $m\otimes 0 = 0= 0\otimes n$.  But here, since the group(s) figuring in the tensor product is multiplicative, the role of the (non-existent) additive $0$ is played by the multiplicative $1\in F^\times$. Hence $a\otimes 1 = 0$ - but I just included that fact in the answer  to emphasize that multiplication in $F^\times$ 'manifests itself' as addition in the tensor product.

Comment: Right. Having that 1 there was just so confusing to me that I didn't even see that there is nothing to do here